# New Relic rake alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I was able to configure new relic to monitor my rake task thanks to [newrelic-rake](https://github.com/xinminlabs/newrelic-rake) gem. Now, my rake tasks are under **Transactions** tab, in the **rake** option from transaction type select box. Those rake tasks are working every few minutes, thanks to cron job. And my questions is:

**How can I assign alert from new relic, if rake task will throw an error?**

I mean, I know I can create alerts if the whole app throws certain amount of errors, or memory consumption is too high, but how assign it to specific rake task? Do I need to upgrade my account to pro subscription level and use [key transaction alert](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/alert-policies/understanding-alert-policies/key-transaction-alerting)? I was trying to use new [beta alerts system](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/new-relic-alerts-beta) but it seems that I cannot assign rake task anywhere.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to pro and defining a Key Transaction in your rake task should do it. Without upgrading, there are a couple other things to try.

If you have access to [custom metrics alerting](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/new-relic-alerts-beta/configuring-alert-policies/define-custom-metrics-alert-condition), you might be able to count your rake errors there.

You can also report your rake tasks do a different NewRelic application and set up alerts on that one. NewRelic will look for a `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME` environment variable at startup, which you can set to `my-rake-tasks`. If you want them to continue reporting to the main application too, you can separate multiple names with semicolons:

```
NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME='my-app;my-rake-tasks' rake foo
```

You might also consider some of the dedicated error reporting services, like [HoneyBadger](https://www.honeybadger.io/) or [Airbrake](http://airbrake.io/), which may have more focused tools.

Comment: That's a great idea. I will need to check this out, Thanks!